# Loop of custom post type names

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I have a lot of different custom post types like person, company, nonprofit, etc. I want to show a loop of their names but I also need to exclude some. Is there a way to give certain post types a shared label that I can then use as an argument to loop through them?

Comment: Just to confirm - you want to loop through the post types themselves, rather than their posts?

Comment: Correct. Like person, company, nonprofit

Comment: Ok cool. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a way, in WP's native features, to give a post type, itself, `meta`.

You can get post types in your code using `get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator )`.

```
$post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types

But the only way I can think of to exclude post types based on a mutual value/variable is by setting relevant `post type settings` when registering the `post type`' - e.g. `'publicly_queryable' => false`.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

And then, you can use `get_post_types()` to find only the post types that have a particaulr value of, for example, `publicly_queryable`.

This may suffice for what you're trying to do. There is no 'post type meta` in WordPress to allow you to set a 'shared label' for the post types themselves.

If my fix above doesn't suffice, then maybe this plugin will be a good place to start (or at least look at it's code) -https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-post-type-meta/.